# netbeans - adding a web service client from a wsdl url with whitepaces

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, wsdl

I am trying to add a wsdl based webservice to my project.

the problem is that the link has spaces in it, and so netbeans says that the link syntex in wrong. "URI Syntex Error"

ip..../Local%20NPG/TELZAR/Comm%20Layer/NPG-Services.serviceagent?wsdl

[image: error netbeans]

Answer (score 0):

I guess whitespace is replaced by "%20" in your end point url.
Modify your wsdl, replace %20 with actual whitespace. May be it work in your case.

you can find end point url in wsdl under  tag

for example:
- -

Comment: it doesn't work because netbeans doesnt allow me to use a url with whitespace or %20, doesn't matter.